# Javascript - Test for null in filter

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Looking for advice on how I can test for null using my filter. It works as long as none of the fields have a "null" assigned to them. If any one of the records has a null, it returns the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of null

Thanks in advance, and any help is greatly appreciated!

```
        computed: { 
            items () {
                    return this.keyword
                    ? this.records.filter(item =>
                        item.name.includes(this.keyword) ||
                        item.location.includes(this.keyword) ||
                        item.status.includes(this.keyword) || 
                        item.vendor.includes(this.keyword) ||
                        item.model.includes(this.keyword) ||
                        item.serial.includes(this.keyword) ||
                        item.product_number.includes(this.keyword)

                    )
                    : this.records
            },
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean item? if so this might help `if (item === null) {return;}`

Comment: what are the values/types of `this.keyword`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something called [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

```js
return this.keyword ? this.records.filter(item =>
                        item.name?.includes(this.keyword) ||
                        item.location?.includes(this.keyword) ||
                        item.status?.includes(this.keyword) || 
                        item.vendor?.includes(this.keyword) ||
                        item.model?.includes(this.keyword) ||
                        item.serial?.includes(this.keyword) ||
                        item.product_number?.includes(this.keyword)

                    )
                    : this.records
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors is happening because at least one of your object properties is set to null. I would create a new function to handle all of your use cases and null checks.

```
computed: { 
    items () {
        return this.keyword
            ? this.records.filter(item =>
                this.checkProperty(item.name) ||
                this.checkProperty(item.location) ||
                this.checkProperty(item.status) ||
                this.checkProperty(item.vendor) || 
                this.checkProperty(item.model) ||
                this.checkProperty(item.serial) ||
                this.checkProperty(item.product_number)
            )
            : this.records
     },
}

checkProperty(prop) {
    return prop ? prop.includes(this.keyword) : false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This solution returns the following error: TypeError: prop.includes is not a function

Comment: Ok, I don't understand why you are getting that error but I'm glad someone else gave you an answer

Answer (score 0):

You could define an array of keys

```
const keys = ['name', 'location', 'status', 'vendor', 'model', 'serial', 'product_number'];
```

and take later another iteration for the keys with a [optional chaining operator `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

```
this.keyword
    ? this.records.filter(item => keys.some(key => item[key]?.includes(this.keyword)))
    : this.records
```